# Why was one of my questions deleted without any indication of why?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had posted a question a while back, it never received much attention, and was never answered, but I still would be interested in getting an answer.

However, today I got an `Organizer` badge for deleting the question, when I never deleted it.  The question does not even indicate why it was deleted, or by who.  All it says is "deleted 2 hours ago".

The question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602557/why-dont-file-type-filters-work-properly-using-nsifilepicker-in-firefox-on-mac-o

So what happened?

Comment: I do find that Organizer badge award rather strange. That badge is for retagging, not deleting. Also, maybe you can vote to undelete it if you'd still like to see it answered (not that I have an answer myself).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was automatically got deleted because of this most likely, since you asked that question Apr 8, 2010 (a year ago)

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

- less than (question age in days * 1.5) views
- 0 score or lower
- no answers
- 1 comment or less
- asked more than 1 year ago

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ was improved to better document this case.

See https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

The 404 page directly links to this as well.

Comment: Any idea why he got an Organizer badge when the post was deleted, rather than a year ago when he retagged it?

Comment: How come this wasn't done by Community ♦?  Or, if it was, why isn't that shown?